# Pandas Regex: Read specific columns only from csv with regex patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a large CSV file(large enough to exceed RAM), I want to read only specific columns following some patterns. The columns can be any of the following: `S_0, S_1, ...D_1, D_2` etc. For example, a chunk from the data frame looks like this:

[image]

And the regex pattern would be for example anyu column that starts with `S`: `S_\d.*`.

Now, how do I apply this with `pd.read_csv(/path/, __)` to read the specific columns as mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

You can first read few rows and try `DataFrame.filter` to get possible columns

```py
cols = pd.readcsv('path', nrows=10).filter(regex='S_\d*').columns
df = pd.readcsv('path', usecols=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Took the same approach(as of now) as mentioned in the comments. Here goes the detailed piece I used:

```py
def extract_col_names(all_cols, pattern):
    result = []
    
    for col in all_cols:
        if re.match(pattern, col):
            result.append(col)
        else:
            continue
            
    return result

extract_col_names(cols, pattern="S_\d+")
```

And it works!
But without this work-around, say even loading the columns is heavy enough itself. So, does there exist any method to parse regex patterns at the time of reading CSVs? This still remains a question.

Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the `usecols` parameter as follows:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

pattern = 'S_\d+'


df = pd.read_csv('path/your_file.csv', usecols=lambda col: bool(re.match(pattern, col)))
```